# Связь между двумя классами

Tags: c#, классы, asp.net-mvc

Нужно сделать простой таск-менеджер, предполагаются две сущности - Пользователь и Задача.
Пользователь заходит в программу и работает со своими задачами.
**Task.cs**

```
public class Task
{
    public const int NameLength = 30;

    [Required]
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }

    [Required, MaxLength(NameLength)]
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual User User { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual bool IsActive { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
}
```

**User.cs**

```
public class User
{
    [Required]
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }

    [Required, MaxLength(NameLength)]
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }

    [Required, MaxLength(EmailLength)]
    public virtual string Email { get; set; }

    [Required, MaxLength(PasswordHashLength)]
    public virtual string PasswordHash { get; set; }

    [Required, MaxLength(PasswordSaltLength)]
    public virtual string PasswordSalt { get; set; }
}
```

В Task добавлено свойство User, чтобы по Id юзера находить связанные с ним задачи.
Не могу понять, как лучше сделать, имеет ли смысл в Юзера добавить список связанных с ним Задач?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, в класс User добавить свойство List<Task> Tasks

Comment: Вот такой вот код http://pastebin.com/FJ9J5WsA правильно?